# electron: how to test a MAS package before submitting to the apple store?

Tags: electron, electron-packager

After a lot of pains and tribulations I managed to build my app using Electron 7 and electron-packager. All works fine when I create a local .app and also when I run npm start.

Now the MAS generation is fine but I can't run the APP. I suspect that this is normal due to sandboxing permissions. But now apple is saying this:

> We discovered one or more bugs in your app when reviewed on Mac
>   running macOS 10.15.
>
> - UI buttons (folder, save, print) do not appear to work
> - File > Open does not appear to work

How can I reproduce this error/run the .app from the mas folder before submitting it again ?

Answer (score 1):

You can test the app locally by re-signing with a Developer ID certificate/provisioning profile. These are also for distribution (just not through MAS), and in theory should produce something very similar to the MAS build.

> Developer ID-signed apps can be run by anyone. However, code that uses
> technologies only available to Mac App Store apps, such as receipt
> validation, iCloud, and push notifications, will not work if your app
> is Developer ID-signed. You might need to temporarily disable those
> parts of your app if you opt for the Developer ID testing approach.
> https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1884/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40015141

Comment: This looks like comment, not an answer.